# Как ускорить программу?

Tags: python-3.x

Два различных натуральных числа называются дружественными, если первое из них равно сумме делителей второго числа, за исключением самого второго числа, а второе равно сумме делителей первого числа, за исключением самого первого числа. Требуется найти все пары дружественных чисел, оба из которых принадлежат промежутку от M до N.

Входные данные:

В первой строке находятся числа M и N. 1 <= M <= N <= 1 000 000, все числа целые.

Выходные данные:

В каждой строке вывести по паре чисел через пробел. Первое число пары должно быть меньше второго. Строки должны быть отсортированы в порядке возрастания первого числа пары. Если пар дружественных чисел в промежутке нет, вывести "Absent".
Мой код:

```
def sd(k):
    s = 0
    m = int(k**0.5)
    for i in range(1, m+1):
        if k%i == 0:
            if i**2 == k:
                s += i    
            else:
                s+=i
                s+=(k//i)
    s -= k
    return s

a = input().split()
n,m = int(a[0]), int(a[1])
f = 0
for i in range(n, m):
    for j in range(i+1, m+1):
        if sd(i) == j and sd(j) == i:
            print(i, j)
            f = 1
if f == 0:
    print('Absend')
```

Однако в системе на одном из тестов не заходит по времени, как ускорить программу?

Comment: Как минимум не вычислять каждый раз делители (ну и их сумму) для одного и того же числа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**первая итерация** - вычислить сначала сумму делителей и только потом с ними работать

```
n = 10000

# получить соответствие число - делитель
numbers = [0,]

for value in range(1, n):
    dividers = 1
    for i in range(2, value):
        if value % i == 0:
            dividers += i
    numbers.append(dividers)

# вывести все пары дружественных чисел
for value1 in range(1, n):
    for value2 in range(1, value1 + 1):
        if value1 == numbers[value2] and value2 == numbers[value1]:
            print(value1, value2)
```

при этом рассматривать не все пары чисел, а только пары в которых первое число больше или равно второму (чтобы избежать дублирование пар)  - тогда будет выполняться всего n^2 / 2 действий

при этом самое долгое в данном алгоритме - вычисление делителей

про n=1000000 говорить не приходится (будет очень долго считаться, минуты)

**вторая итерация** - нет надобности проверять все делители от 2 до n, достаточно определять делители от 2 до n / 2 - это ускоряет алгоритм в 2 раза:

```
# получить соответствие число - делитель
numbers = [0,]

for value in range(1, n):
    dividers = 1
    for i in range(2, value // 2 + 1):
        if value % i == 0:
            dividers += i
    numbers.append(dividers)
```

**итерация №3** - алгоритм поиска суммы делителей можно немного ускорить (в полтора-два раза) если переписать код через функции питона (не знаю почему так получается):

```
for value in range(1, n):
    dividers = 1 + sum(i for i in range(2, value // 2 + 1) if value % i == 0)
    numbers.append(dividers)
```

можно свернуть в чуть более короткий код (но такая же скорость работы)

```
# получить соответствие число - делитель
numbers = [(1 + sum(i for i in range(2, value // 2 + 1) if value % i == 0)) for value in range(1, n)]
```

**итерация №4** - делители можно рассматривать до sqrt(value), но тогда необходимо дополнительно учитывать и вторые делители - value // i:

```
for value in range(1, n):
    dividers = 1 + sum((i + value // i) for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(value)) + 1) if value % i == 0)
    numbers.append(dividers)
```

или

```
numbers = [(1 + sum((i + value // i) for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(value)) + 1) if value % i == 0)) for value in range(1, n)]
```

Comment: Тогда уж ограничивать цикл до `sqrt(value)+1`. И сразу добавлять оба делителя - i и value // i.

Comment: @GrAnd, да, дошел до этого, просто надо учитывать вторые делители при этом, т.е. `value / divider`